# Problemas con loadStationData() (climate4R)

Tags: r

Siguiendo los ejemplos de este [link](http://meteo.unican.es/work/loadeR/wiki/html/OaccessingLoadingStationData.html), solo tengo problemas con la función loadStationData(), que entrega esta advertencia:

```
gsn <- "mydirectory/GSN_World"
di <- dataInventory(dataset = gsn)
gsnload <- loadStationData(gsn, var = "tmean")

Error in .jcall("RJavaTools", "Ljava/lang/Object;", "invokeMethod", cl,  : 
  java.io.FileNotFoundException: mydirectory\GSN_World (Acceso denegado)
```

Cual podría ser la solución?
Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que hice fue:

1. Desinstalar Java (jdk, jre) de mi PC, los volvi a descargar (jdk1.8.0 y jre1.8.0) y los instale.
2. Pase de utilizar R version 4.0.2 a 3.6.3 e instale los paquetes de climate4R de la siguiente manera

```
# Instalacion paquetes climate4R ----
# Verificar si ya tienes instalado 'devtools' para descargar desde github

library(devtools)

install_github(c("SantanderMetGroup/loadeR.java",
                 "SantanderMetGroup/climate4R.UDG@devel",
                 "SantanderMetGroup/loadeR",
                 "SantanderMetGroup/transformeR",
                 "SantanderMetGroup/visualizeR",
                 "SantanderMetGroup/downscaleR"))

# si tienes problemas con 'rlang', 'ellipsis', 'fansi', instalalos manualmente y vuelve a instalar visualizeR
install_github("SantanderMetGroup/visualizeR")

install_github("SantanderMetGroup/downscaleR")
```

Y listo!